# How to use Hazelcast MapStore data in the IMap

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast in my application..

In the first step I'm loading all the table data into MapStore..

```
public class PersonMapStore implements MapStore<String, Person> {

    private final Connection con;
    private final PreparedStatement allKeysStatement;

    
    public PersonMapStore() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            System.out.println("hello");
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:", "", "");
            con.createStatement().executeUpdate(
                    "create table if not exists person (id varchar(45) not null, name varchar(45), primary key (id))");
            allKeysStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM public.person");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        
    }
```

model class

```
public class Person {
    
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private HazelcastJsonValue object_value;
    
    public Person() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

MapStore Configurartion

```
public void mapConf() {
        Config config = new Config();
        MapConfig mapCfg = new MapConfig();
        mapCfg.setName("data");
        mapCfg.setBackupCount(2);
        mapCfg.getMaxSizeConfig().setSize(10000);
        mapCfg.setTimeToLiveSeconds(300);

        MapStoreConfig mapStoreCfg = new MapStoreConfig();
        mapStoreCfg.setClassName(PersonMapStore.class.getName()).setEnabled(true);
        mapCfg.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreCfg);

        // use near cache if needed
        NearCacheConfig nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig();
        nearCacheConfig.setMaxSize(1000).setMaxIdleSeconds(120).setTimeToLiveSeconds(300);
        mapCfg.setNearCacheConfig(nearCacheConfig);

        config.addMapConfig(mapCfg);
        
         HazelcastInstance hazelCast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
         IMap<String, Person> hazelInstance = hazelCast.getMap("data");
         
         System.out.println(hazelInstance.size());
//giving size 0 but i have 2 rows data in the database
    }
}
```

So now how to transfer/Store all the MapStore data into the Hazelcast

```
HazelcastInstance hazelCast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IMap<Integer, HazelcastJsonValue> hazelInstance = hazelCast.getMap("data");
```

So that i can perform all the query operation using IMap..

How to configure the MapStore and use the MapStore in the IMap?